# r raster to polygon shows a regular grid even if cells had different area?

Tags: r, projection, r-raster

I am converting a raster to polygons. In my initial raster, cells have different area, but when I convert to polygon using `rasterToPolygons` and plot it, I see an equi-distant grid, even though initial cells had different area?

Is it an issue with my R code, or an issue with my bad understanding of projections? How could I do to represent the polygons with area proportional to the cells area?

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r$value <- 1:ncell(r)
r$area <- as.data.frame(area(r))$layer

head(as.data.frame(r))

ras_to_pol <- rasterToPolygons(r)
spplot(ras_to_pol, "area", main="Area of initial cells converted to polygons")
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are not specifying the resolution of the cells nor the extent of the raster or the projection. 
Therefore `raster` defaults to:

```
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

and since you are using `nrow=18, ncol=36` you will get cells of 10 degrees both on latitude and longitude, and therefore "square" cells when you plot them in "cartesian coordinates" on a plane.

However, in geographic coordinates the *area* of the surface of the "spheroid" corresponding to a 10x10 degrees cell actually changes with latitude (See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29743 and here https://badc.nerc.ac.uk/help/coordinates/cell-surf-area.html for an explanation), as shown by the "colours" on your plot.

If you want to have polygons with variable "area" you have to reproject to an equal-area projection. There are many: here I'm using a Conical Equal Area as an example:

```
ras_to_pol_new  <- spTransform(ras_to_pol, CRS("+init=epsg:3410"))
spplot(ras_to_pol_new, "area", main="Area of initial cells converted to polygons")
```

[image]

You can see how the area of the polygons decreases with latitude. 
(For a very good primer on projections, you can see for example: https://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Map%20projections/mappro.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So the issue comes that I am plotting in the cartesian coordinates? Which coordinate system/projection should I use to have the cells with "shape" proportional to their area?

Comment: Well, not really from the fact that you are using "cartesian coordinates". More from the fact that a geographic projection cannot (I think) be equal area. To see the "variable areas" you need to reproject to an equal area projection (see the edited answer).